# Define two functions $c(x) = \max\{x - a,0\}$, $p(x) = \max\{a-x,0\}$. Prove that $c(x) - p(x) = x - a$

Tags: real-analysis

Define two functions $c(x) = \max\{x - a,0\}$, $p(x) = \max\{a-x,0\}$. Prove that $c(x) - p(x) = x - a$

The question is from a topic in Sets and Functions notes. Can I add an Indicator function here?
How can after subtraction, the answer be $(x - a)$

Any helps, hints, solutions, thoughts are welcomed

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compute $c(x)-p(x)$ for $x\geq a$ and $x<a$.

**Remark:** You can generalize it. For a function $f$ you call $f^+(x):=\max\{f(x),0\}$ the positiv part of $f$ and $f^-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}$ the negative part of $f$. Then you have $f=f^+-f^-$. This is used for measure theory, where you start to define the integral for nonnegative functions. To prove $f=f^+-f^-$ you have to consider it pointwise. For $x$ you have either $f(x)\geq 0$ or $f(x)<0$. And on both cases you just use the definition of $f^+$ and $f^-$ and compute $f^+(x)-f^-(x)=\ldots=f(x)$.

In your case you have $f(x)=x-a$, $c(x)=f^+(x)$ and $p(x)=f^-(x)$.

Comment: If I want to break down f−(x) or f+(x), say f+(x) => will it be x-a if  x>=a, 0 if x<k ;   OR otherwise. Could you please show how to break it down.

Comment: You don't need the notation from my remark. But you are right. By definition $c(x)=x-a$ if $x\geq a$ and $c(x)=0$ if $x<a$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Start by proving that in general: $$b=\max(b,0)-\max(-b,0)$$This by discerning the cases $b\geq0$ and $b\leq0$.

Answer (score 0):

$p(x)=\max\{a-x,0\}=-\min\{x-a,0\}$, so $c(x)-p(x)=\max\{x-a,0\}+\min\{x-a,0\}=(x-a)+0=x-a$.